# Python version conflict

Tags: python, python-3.x, path-variables

I have installed python version Python 3.7.8 and added it to path variables.
However when i type python in the cmd i get python 2.6

[image]

If you see the below image, python 3.7 is added to the path variable!
[image]

**How can i open python 3.7 from cmd instead of 2.6?**

Comment: command is python3

Comment: Do you really need also python2.6? Just uninstall both than clean install python3 (preferably the latest version)

Comment: On windows, to access `python 3` use `py -3`

Comment: the environment variable ``PATH`` is evaluated left-to-right. If your Python 2.x bin folder is found first, the ``python.exe`` will be started from there. So either make sure to add your Python 3 path to the start of ``PATH`` or make sure to remove your Python 2 path from ``PATH``. Simply type ``PATH`` into your console to check its contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for python 2.x use py -2.x or -2 for latest 2.x
for python 3.x use py -3.x or -3 for latest 3.x